# Apache NiFi: Output to multiple FlowFiles simultaneously?

Tags: java, apache-nifi

Is there a way to simultaneously write to different streams in a custom processor in NiFi? For instance I have third party libraries that do significant processing using APIs that work something like this:

```
public void process(InputStream in, OutputStream foo, OutputStream baa, List<String> args)
{
    ...
    foo.write(things);
    baa.write(stuff);
    ...
}
```

But the only examples I can find all just use one output stream:

```
FlowFile transform = session.write(original, new OutputStreamCallback() {
        @Override
        public void process(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
            out.write("stuff");
        }
    });
```

Processing is done in batches, (due to its large scale), so its not practical to perform all the processing then write out the separate flows.

The only way I can come up with is process the input multiple times :(

To clarify, I want to write to multiple FlowFiles, using the `session.write(flowfile, callback)` method, so the different streams can be sent/managed separately

Comment: Is the use of [TeeOutputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html) out of the question ? See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987395/how-to-write-data-to-two-java-io-outputstream-objects-at-once

Comment: I dont think so, the only way I know of writing to a flowfile is using the OutputStreamCallback, which has only one function (process), which takes only one argument (an OutputStream).

Comment: Yes, but a TeeOutputStream allows you to have 1 stream that writes to 2 separate files, isn(t that enough ?

Comment: I don't believe so, TeeOutputStream writes the same thing to both streams, my functions do not (such as "things" and "stuff" in my example). Thanks

Comment: Also, I want to write to multiple _flowfiles_ (this isn't clear, i'll update the question) using the session.write(flowfile, callback) method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NiFi API is based on acting upon one flow file at a time, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
        FlowFile flowFile1 = session.create();
        final AtomicReference<FlowFile> holder = new AtomicReference<>(session.create());

        flowFile1 = session.write(flowFile1, new OutputStreamCallback() {
            @Override
            public void process(OutputStream out) throws IOException {

                FlowFile flowFile2 = session.write(holder.get(), new OutputStreamCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(OutputStream out) throws IOException {

                    }
                });
                holder.set(flowFile2);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks this works. My only change would be make the first OutputStream a different name (and final) so you can write to both in the inner-inner function.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're making different outputs from the same input you might also consider having these steps be broken out as discrete processors that focus on doing their specific function.  Above you show "things" and "stuff" so for example I'm suggesting you have a 'DoThings' and 'DoStuff' processor.  In your flow you can send the same flowfile to both by simply using the source connection twice.  This then enables nice parallel operations and allows them to have different runtimes/etc.  NiFi will still maintain the provenance trail for you and it won't actually be copying the bytes at all but rather passing a pointer to the original content.

Comment: I agree this is has its advantages, but if there is a large amount of processing done per input stream, it feels wasteful to throw it all away and do it again (or twice in parallel). Its a trade-off. Thanks though.

Comment: Could you do the intermediate (or "shared") processing in a single processor and then split to two subsequent processors when the actions differ? Nothing says that the flowfile content had to be in a certain state when processor A finishes, as long as B and B' can both accept the output of A as input.