# Render itext pdf as a web page and save it same to a DB in one go (using Spring)

Tags: stream, itext

```
@Override
protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(response.getOutputStream());
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
    Document doc = new Document(pdf);
```

with the above code, I am rendering a pdf as an html response. When I do that, I also want to save this to the database. How should I do it?

Should I create another byte stream and redo the same steps?

Comment: If you *redo the same steps*, you'll get a slightly different pdf with changes in metadata like creation time and document ID. Instead either target the `PdfWriter` to a `ByeArrayOutputStream` and write the resulting byte array to all outputs you want your pdf to go to, or use something like explained in [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7987395/1729265).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!